# git not adding existing folder

Tags: git

I started working on a project recently, then decided to push it up to github. So I did the following:

```
cd <root>
git init
git add -A
git commit -m 'message'
git remote add origin <ur>
git push -u origin master
```

this, however, omitted an entire folder of my project. its basically a folder 1 level down from my root folder so:

```
root
 -folder //omitted
```

I'm trying to do `git add -A / git add * / git add .` but every time I do `git status` it says there are changes but the folder is untracked.

I even tried to specifically add the folder `git add folderName` but `git status` is still showing it as untracked.

I also tried to navigate into the folder itself, and do a `git add *` and that added everything INSIDE of this folder, but I just cant seem to add the folder itself.

any idea what else I can do?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Are there files in the folder? Git doesn't track folders, only files; you can't add an empty folder to a Git repo. However, you can put an empty file in that folder (`.gitignore` or `.blank` are common file names) and add those files to the folder.

Comment: there are a bunch of files in there. quote from my question `'I also tried to navigate into the folder itself, and do a git add * and that added everything INSIDE of this folder, but I just cant seem to add the folder itself.'`

Comment: @AbdulAhmad: If it added the files, then cloning the repo should automatically create the containing directory. Is that not happening?

Comment: what do you mean by cloning the repo? I haven't cloned it. Should I? You mean pushing up to remote?

Comment: actually its strange. When I navigate into the folder, it shows me all these new files that are added/modified and tracked ready to be committed. But when I cd out to the root folder, it doesnt show all those new files. But the root of my repo is in the root folder. Does it matter which folder I'm pushing from? or should I do the `git push` command from root?

Comment: I was just looking through the folder structure and there was a `.git` folder in that folder that was being omitted. after deleting that, things seem to be working more normally

Answer (score 26):

A subfolder will not be added with `git add .` (or similar commands) if it contains a `.git` dir because it will be assumed to be a git submodule.

You can `rm -rf .git` in the subfolder if it's not supposed to be a submodule.

Comment: After spending for an hour, I found that the issue is due .git folder inside backend folder

Answer (score 0):

In sourcetree change the selection from pending to ignored.  Then add the files you want.